# Difficult SQL query all and any case

Tags: sql, sqlite

I don't know how to write an sql query.

Given data:
several trait identifiers integers - let say 1 and 447.

I'm looking for domain_ids in which I will find snp that is assigned to particular trait. SNP is in the domain when its `genomic_pos` is between domain `start` and `end` and `chr_id` is the same. There are two cases *any* and *all*:

- *all* case I'm looking for domains in which I can find snps from all given traits. In other words all the traits have their snp representant in the domain.
- *any* case I'm looking for domains in which I can find snps from any of given domains. In other words it is enough to find only one snp representant of any trait in the domain.

I've already solved the *any* case, but i stuck with *all* case :(

Here is the *any* code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT domains.domain_id
FROM snps JOIN traits_snps ON snps.snp_id     = traits_snps.snp_id
       JOIN traits      ON traits.trait_id = traits_snps.trait_id
       JOIN chromosomes ON snps.chr_id     = chromosomes.chr_id
       JOIN domains     ON domains.chr_id  = chromosomes.chr_id
WHERE traits.trait_id in (447,1 )   --  <-- HERE GOES TRAIT IDS
   AND genomic_pos BETWEEN start AND end 
   AND domains.chr_id = snps.chr_id;
```

Here is my DB in SQLite. [image]

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` is very often an indicator for a poorly written query, where you build a large intermediate result by uneccessarily joining tables only to have to dismiss many rows as duplicates later. Please see my answer on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do what you want with `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT d.domain_id
FROM snps s JOIN
     traits_snps ts
     ON s.snp_id = ts.snp_id JOIN
     traits t
     ON t.trait_id = ts.trait_id JOIN
     chromosomes c
     ON s.chr_id  = c.chr_id JOIN
     domains d
     ON d.chr_id = c.chr_id AND
        d.chr_id = s.chr_id  -- JOIN conditions should be in ON clauses
WHERE t.trait_id in (447, 1) AND --  <-- HERE GOES TRAIT IDS
      genomic_pos BETWEEN start AND end 
GROUP BY d.domain_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.trait_id) = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

To find domains for which some data exists in other tables, use `WHERE EXISTS`.

ANY case: Find domains that have an snp in the given range in connection with at least one of the traits:

```
select domain_id
from domains d
where exists
(
  select *
  from snps
  where snps.chr_id = d.chr_id
  and snps.genomic_pos between d.start and d.end 
  and snps.snp_id in (select snp_id from traits_snps where trait_id in (447, 1))
);
```

ALL case: Find domains that have an snp in the given range in connection with all of the traits:

```
select domain_id
from domains d
where exists
(
  select *
  from snps
  where snps.chr_id = d.chr_id
  and snps.genomic_pos between d.start and d.end 
  and snps.snp_id in
  (
    select snp_id 
    from traits_snps
    where trait_id in (447, 1)
    group by snp_id
    having count(distinct trait_id) = 2
  )
);
```

Comment: I think you miss that snp and traits are in many-to-many relationship. `select snp_id from traits where trait_id in (447, 1);` fails. But I'm almost home. Thank you.

Comment: @user31027: I was aware of that, but maybe I misunderstood your request. I am looking for domains with at least one snp with at least one (resp. with all) of the given traits. Maybe you want all the domain's snps to fulfill the request or something else that my query doesn't cover.

Comment: But how can it work if sub-sub-select can't even execute? `traits` table don't have `snp_id` column.

Comment: Oops, sorry, it must be `traits_snps` and not `traits` in the query of course.